# ¿Por qué no verifica el capcha?

Tags: php, html, ajax

PROBLEMA ¿POR QUE NO SE ENVIA EL CAPTCHA por medio de ajax, O como lo capturo y envió agradezco la ayuda? ya he buscado y no consigo algo util en la web o no logro entender la consola.

tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="name0" name="name0" placeholder="Tu Email" onkeypress="registro();"></div>
<div class="mb-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" id="name1" name="name1" placeholder="Contraseña" style="margin: 0px;margin-bottom: 14px;">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="name2" name="name2" placeholder="Repita su Contraseña" style="margin: 0px;margin-bottom: 14px;">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="name3" name="name3" placeholder="Nombre" style="margin: 0px;margin-bottom: 14px;">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="name4" name="name4" placeholder="Apellido" style="margin: 0px;margin-bottom: 14px;">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="name5" name="name5" placeholder="Whatsapp" style="margin: 0px;margin-bottom: 14px;"></div>
<div id="name6" name="name6" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld5U8UUAAAAAM_Ghlp4ocZor4UKtBbKI2HW_fa_" onmouseout="registro();"></div>
 <div><button class="btn btn-primary d-block w-100" type="submit">Iniciar session</button></div>
</form>
```

Hago el capture de los ID con el siguiente cogigo:

```
    function registro(){
    var mail        = document.getElementById('name0').value;
    var w1      = document.getElementById('name1').value;
    var w2      = document.getElementById('name2').value;
    var ame         = document.getElementById('name3').value;
    var astname     = document.getElementById('name4').value;
    var hatsapp     = document.getElementById('name5').value;
    var oken        = document.getElementById('name6').value = token;
    var perimetros = {
        'email'             : mail,
        'Pw1'               : w1,
        'Pw2'               : w2,
        'name'              : ame,
        'lastname'          : astname,
        'whatsapp'          : hatsapp,
        'token'             : oken
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: perimetros,
        url: '../assets/Registro.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            $('#resulsig').html(response);
        }
        success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        //console.log("Form successfully submited");
        }
    });
}
```

Lo que tengo lo envió a un archivo php con el siguiente codigo:

```
    <?php
    echo "Aquí debe mostrar todos los POST que salen ("; print_r($_POST); echo")";
    ?>
```

deberia llegar algo aqui de **token** en el array pero nunca sale nada mas que esto:

> Aqui debe mostrar todos los POST que salen (Array ( [email] => mi email [Pw1] => mi pass 1 [Pw2] => mi pass 2 [name] => mi nombre [lastname] => mi apellido [whatsapp] => +5555555555558 ) )

Comment: hola, es porque el valor de tu token lo Tenes un `data-attribute`, tendrias que requerir ese valor usando `dataset` en tu caso quedaría así: `document.getElementById('name6').dataset.sitekey`

Comment: he intentado lo que dices pero solo envía el sitekey **6Ld5U8UUAAAAAM_Ghlp4ocZor4UKtBbKI2HW_fa_** por lo tanto **no el token**  que es mucho mas largo como saco el token tengo acesso a todo pero no logro sacar esa duda

Comment: esta bien pero eso ya lo Tenes que validar en tu php, ya llevaste el sitekey, con php lo comparas con tu clave secreta y con eso ya podes hacer la validación

Comment: ok es que no entiendo como seria ese procedimiento